# How to add a new copy of view to Tabcontrol in the Shell?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, tabcontrol

MEF+DirectoryCatalog+OnDemand

I have a code Initialize() in ModuleB:

```
this.regionManager.AddToRegion("TabRegion", new Views.Container());
this.regionManager.AddToRegion("TabRegion", new Views.Container());
```

and click event on the Shell:

```
modulemanager.LoadModule("ModuleB");
```

as a result I see 2 tabs in the shell tabcontrol

for me the problem is to call again:

```
this.regionManager.AddToRegion("TabRegion", new Views.Container());
```

How to do that?
many thanks

PS
I've tried to find solution in the web, but I guess that my question is not proper.

Comment: It is better if you make an answer of your solution, and then mark it as answer (click on hollow check mark).

Comment: :) it is surprise for me, somebody's edited my post! thanks, I will edit some code style by the way.

Comment: stackoverflow is setup to have good, community maintained, questions and answers, so anyone can edit any post (although if they make a bad edit other people will undo it).

Answer (score 0):

If this code is called **only** from ModuleB constructor (or from some nested method), then the only way for you is to create another instance of ModuleB. Here is article that may help you: [Dynamic Part Instantiation in MEF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nblumhardt/archive/2009/08/28/dynamic-part-instantiation-in-mef.aspx).

But if you can make that method static, then you can call it later as meny times as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the EventAggregator:

1. Create Infrastucture project with
   PublishModuleAgainer:CompositePresentationEvent class
2. Point Importing constructor to Shell initializing

   ```
   public Shell(IEventAggregator _eventaggregator);
   ```
3. Call in runtime

   ```
   eventaggregator.GetEvent().Publish("STOCK0");
   ```
4. In Initialize() of module subscribe to event

   ```
   eventaggregator.GetEvent().Subscribe(CreateView);
   ```
5. Just create Action CreateView and call add2region inside it:

   ```
   this.regionManager.AddToRegion("TabRegion", new Views.Container());
   ```

Link to the same question and an answer [Loading a prism module view from the shell, using MEF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573376/loading-a-prism-module-view-from-the-shell-using-mef)

Comment: Please, do not delete the link in the answer!